# Build Fails with "Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'" with Illegal char

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated my build tools (26.0.2), gradle (3.0.0), sdk, and Android Studio (3.0) files, and now I get the following error when I try to build:

```
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> Illegal char <:> at index 2: \C:\Users\drew\.gradle\caches\transforms-
1\files-1.1\libjingle9803.aar\82e26da2d02a54a61bc87346a7bdcab9\jars\libs\libjingle_peerconnection.jar\..\..\tmpKgXRtF\.empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

I've tried deleting that .gradle\caches folder, I've uninstalled and re-installed everything, but I still get the same error.  Also, when I try searching for this same error, I see alot of the same error, but the cause is usually a duplicate file, which doesn't help much here.

Any ideas on what I can try next?  Also, it's not clear to me which file(s) I can add here to be more helpful with the problem; I'll be happy to post any requested files.

build.gradle (for project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/' }
    }

}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
//        applicationId "org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample"
        applicationId "com.floor2labs.qtbp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
        versionCode 8
        versionName "0.8"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "QTbp-$versionCode")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.QTbp
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public' }
    //maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-
api'}
    google()
}

dependencies {
    //compile project(':ebson-0.4-20140612.044330-1')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    //compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1'
    //compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile project(':webrtc-client')
}
```

build.gradle (webrtc-client):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9803@aar'        // No Crashes Here, 
Latest Version Before Breaking Changes..
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2'

}
```